# is there a way to change image src in javascript using virtual path in c# mvc 5

Tags: javascript, image, asp.net-mvc-5

im trying to change the image of a img tag in javascript using virtual path

```
    $("#imgSmall-" + FacilityID + FEATID + i).attr("src", "~/ApplicationUploads/Images/FLOWMETER/FLOWMETER-1/wp1.jpg");
    $("#imgBig-" + FacilityID + FEATID + i).attr("href", "~/ApplicationUploads/Images/FLOWMETER/FLOWMETER-1/wp1.jpg");
```

it gets an error 404 not found 
but when i tried it in my view

```
 <img id="imgSmall" src="~/ApplicationUploads/Images/FLOWMETER/FLOWMETER-1/wp1.jpg" class="attachImage img-thumbnail" />
```

Comment: Try "~/Content/...". The static file module/handler looks up files in the Content folder, if I weren't wrong :)

Comment: Omit the leading `~` character - `$("#imgSmall...).attr("src", "/ApplicationUploads/Images/FLOWMETER/FLOWMETER-1/wp1.jpg")`

Comment: thanks for the info i remove the ~ character but it also did not work.
but i already found the answer. i just replace ~ to ..

Comment: The `~` character is evaluated on the server and if you inspect the html that you initial `<img>` tag renders, you would see that it does not have a leading `~` character in the `src` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the url helper:

```
$("#imgSmall-" + FacilityID + FEATID + i).attr("src", "@Url.Content("~/ApplicationUploads/Images/FLOWMETER/FLOWMETER-1/wp1.jpg")");
$("#imgBig-" + FacilityID + FEATID + i).attr("href", "@Url.Content("~/ApplicationUploads/Images/FLOWMETER/FLOWMETER-1/wp1.jpg")");
```